# How to suppress "Comet.ml Experiment Summary" console output in the beginning

Tags: python, jupyter, comet-ml

I'm using `comet.ml` to display learning results of my machine learning models on `jupyter`.

Initializing an experiment as follows

```
experiment = Experiment(project_name='...', auto_metric_logging=False)
experiment.add_tag('...')
```

the following information is shown (with light red color background) in the beginning every time:

```
COMET INFO: ----------------------------
COMET INFO: Comet.ml Experiment Summary:
COMET INFO:   Data:
COMET INFO:     url: https://www.comet.ml/...
COMET INFO:   Metrics [count] (min, max):
COMET INFO:     loss_D_fake [210]            : (1.4689682722091675, 1.999974250793457)
... 50+ lines ...
COMET INFO:     sys.ram.total [8]            : (269603381248.0, 269603381248.0)
COMET INFO:     sys.ram.used [8]             : (60270231552.0, 64912928768.0)
COMET INFO:   Uploads:
COMET INFO:     git-patch: 1
COMET INFO: ----------------------------
COMET INFO: Experiment is live on comet.ml https://www.comet.ml/...
```

All I want to see is the last line that shows the URL for this experiment and that seems not to be included in the 'Comet.ml Experiment Summary' block. How can we suppress other information?

Answer (score 0):

You set the level of display summary with:

```
experiment = Experiment(display_summary_level=0)
```

For more information, please see: https://www.comet.ml/docs/python-sdk/Experiment/#experiment__init__